# Who can I localize text inside resque job?

Tags: ruby, internationalization, resque

I want to use i8ng inside resque job? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should have access to the entire rails stack inside a resque job.

If not you can always do it manually:

```
   require 'i8ln'
   config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/locales/en.yml")
   ...
   ...
```